# Mysql: Counting a matching bulk between two sets of values within multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, search, loops

Is there a way to count a bulk set of matching rows between tables using COUNT() AS number_matches?

I was thinking of including some sort of looping method that satifies a searching algorithm, but before I do that I was wondering/hoping for a more simple approach.

**TABLE_1**

- **Row 1:**

  number_1) 1

  number_2) 2

  number_3) 3

  number_4) 4
- **Row 2:**

  number_1) 2

  number_2) 4

  number_3) 5

  number_4) 6

*compare with*

**TABLE_2**

- **Row 1:**

  number_1) 2

  number_2) 4

  number_3) 6

  number_4) 8

**RESULT**

- **Row 1:**

  number_matches) 2
- **Row 2:**

  number_matches) 3

Comment: Your example is showing rows inside every table? Are those rows or columns?

Comment: They are columns, I've made the example more clear to illustrate. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Every table has many rows, right?

Comment: It fulfills a raffle game scenario, so TABLE_2 should return 1 row, tested with many rows from TABLE_1

Answer (score 1):

Given your example I think you want to count the amount of records of a join, right?

```
select count(*) from table_1 t1
join table_2 t2 on t1.col = t2.col
```

Comment: Or for those of us who despise join syntax for simple queries:select count(*) from table_1 t1, table_2 t2, where t1.col = t2.col

Comment: @AndrewEdvalson: syntax you use is converted from engine in a JOIN; in general it's always better using a JOIN rather than your syntax in more complex queries, because this can avoid cartesian product of tables resulting in huge queries!!

Comment: LOL, just don't have a SQL antipatterns argument in my answer comments :P

Comment: number_* is a column, what if number_1 = number_2... number_2 = number_4, etc?